# Start typing in form on load of document?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make an inventory management system for someone, and one of the goals of it is to just go down an aisle of boxes and go beep-beep-beep with a barcode scanner to log all of UPCs. What I'm trying to do is make it to where when the scanner scans something, the page automatically recognizes some numbers, inserts it into a MySQL table, and the scanner automatically presses enter.

This is the table right now:

```
UPC \ Description \ ID
0123456789  Verdana II  DCI-456
0123456789  Verdana II  DCI-456
0123456789  Verdana II  DCI-456
1122334455  Christmas   CRT-913
6677889900  Harlem Shake    HRL-5HK
6677889900  Harlem Shake    HRL-5HK
6677889900  Harlem Shake    HRL-5HK
6677889900  Harlem Shake    HRL-5HK
6677889900  Harlem Shake    HRL-5HK
9876543210  Beach House DCI-123
9876543210  Beach House DCI-123
```

So it needs to only insert the UPC that it scans, and blank for the rest like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rtamart_incoming (upc)
             VALUES ('9911447755')");
```

I guess in summary: Scan (Numbers, then enter) -> Insert into table

Comment: Do you understand what javascript events the barcode input device triggers?  That is really the key to understanding this problem.  My guess is you would want to use AJAX to call backend script to do the inset, but you need to understand what events are triggered by the input device in order to know what events to attach handlers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to automatically focus a field on page load, but if you're targeting relatively modern browsers, probably the best is to use the [`autofocus` feature that is built into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus).

Basically, you just need to add an `autofocus` attribute to the `input` you're targeting:

```
<form action="something.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <!--                       vvvvvvvvv         -->
    <input id="foo" name="foo" autofocus>
    <!--                       ^^^^^^^^^         -->
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running something other than HTML5 (like most *beep* type devices,) you can use jQuery to automatically focus on the input field upon completion of page loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upc').focus();
  });
</script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="upc" name="upc" />
</form>
```